# Enable drag and drop between itemrenderers

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, itemrenderer

I have two tilelists in my mxml application. The items (image and a label) get rendered by an itemrenderer. The functionality I want to achieve: drag image from tilelist #1 and drop it on tilelist #2 (and then a httpservice with sql query will be launched).

How would I tackle this problem? (high level info would suffice).
The main issue I have is that I don't know how to call methods from the main to my itemrenderer. I would like to code the d&d functionality within the renderer but I have no clue how to access watchlist #2 from within the renderer.
Relevant code in main.mxml:

```
<s:Panel id="panel"  width="100%" height="100%" title="Watchlist">
<s:layout>
<s:VerticalLayout paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="20"
                          paddingRight="20" paddingTop="5"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Label width="20%" fontSize="17" fontWeight="bold" text="Your watched movies"/>
    <mx:TileList id="myWatchedList_tile" height="360" borderVisible="false" width="80%"
                 columnCount="5" columnWidth="200"
                 itemRenderer="components.TileListItemRenderer" rowCount="1" rowHeight="360"/>
    <s:Label width="20%" fontSize="17" fontWeight="bold" text="Your to watch movies"/>


    <mx:TileList id="myToWatchList_tile"  height="360" borderVisible="false" width="80%"
                 columnCount="5" columnWidth="200"
                 itemRenderer="components.TileListItemRenderer" rowCount="1" rowHeight="360" />

</s:Panel>
```

The itemrenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
     borderVisible="false" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
     xmlns:components="components.*">



    <mx:Image source="{data.poster_url}" />
    <mx:Label text="{data.movie_title}" height="20" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access methods outside of your item renderer using the `outerDocument` object. Make sure they are (scope)public methods.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.edu.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution might be to use spark lists instead (with a TileLayout) - then you can easily use drag+drop between lists: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfd.html

..and launch service in response to 'drop' event (event will have reference to dropped image)